# Create and use a random string in Robot

Tags: robotframework

I want to create a random string, assign it to a variable and enter that variable into a text box. How can I do this?

Don't know how to use `SELENIUM.SETTEXT` with the assigned variable. I've done the following so far:

```
${RANUSER} = Generate Random String 6 [LETTERS]
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use Selenium instead of Robot Framework's Selenium2Library? You could you keyword "Input Text    <locator>    ${RANUSER}"

Comment: is the "text box" on a web page, or in some other sort of application? Are you using `Selenium2Library` or some other library?

Answer (score 1):

Have you imported the correct libraries :

```
*** Settings***
Library  Selenium2Library
Library  String

*** Variables ***
${RANUSER}  Generate Random String  10  [LETTERS]

*** Test Cases ***
Enter Random Username
   Input Text  //input[@id='userInput']  ${RANUSER}
```